# Return an object in C#

Tags: c#

I have a method that gets a list of people from the database using aspnet boilerplate framework. Since adding the include line I get the error message:

> Specified cast is not valid

Here is the full error message:

Specified cast is not valid

Here is the c# method:

```
public ListResultDto<PersonListDto> GetPeople(GetPeopleInput input)
{
    var persons = _personRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Include(p => p.Phones)
        .WhereIf(
            !input.Filter.IsNullOrEmpty(),
            p => p.Name.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                    p.Surname.Contains(input.Filter) ||
                    p.EmailAddress.Contains(input.Filter)
        )
        .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
        .ThenBy(p => p.Surname)
        .ToList();

    return new ListResultDto<PersonListDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<PersonListDto>>(persons));
}
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to resolve the issue?

Comment: does it throw on that big linq line? If so break it into pieces to identify which clause is failing

Comment: it breaks on .Include(p => p.Phones)

Comment: does `ListResultDto<PersonListDto>` == `List<PersonListDto>`? what is `ListResultDto<PersonListDto>`?

Comment: don't think so references  https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular#creating-person-entity

Comment: An application service method gets/returns DTOs. ListResultDto is a pre-build helper DTO to return a list of another DTO. GetPeopleInput is a DTO to pass request parameters to GetPeople method. So, GetPeopleIntput and PersonListDto are defined as shown below:

Comment: so `ListResultDto<PersonListDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<PersonListDto>>(persons))` should be `ListResultDto<PersonListDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<ListResultDto<PersonListDto>>(persons))`  ?

Comment: No because that breaks the method and it requires missing references and that shouldn't be needed. I have added custom mappings for person but it still doesnt work as intended

Comment: If i uncomment .Include(p => p.Phones) it works but obviously i can't get phone number

Answer (score 0):

I think its cannot be break on `.Include(p => p.Phones)` line. Because there is nothing about casting. You considered about constructor of the `ListResultDto` class can take `ObjectMapper.Map<List<PersonListDto>>` as parameter. Also maybe you need to change that line with `ObjectMapper.Map<ListResultDto<PersonListDto>>`